# "Next" button creates a Viewed_Lesson | Ruby on Rails 4 | Learning App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to make a **"next" button** that should generate a Viewed_lesson (user_id, lesson_id, boolean: true) and then redirect to the next lesson. The purpose is to make a tracking progress to show the progress of the user over a course.

My models:

```
class Course
    has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson
  #fields: course_id
  belongs_to :course
end
class User
  has_many :viewed_lessons
  has_many :viewed_courses
end
class ViewedLesson
  #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end
class ViewedCourse
  #fields: user_id, course_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course  
end
```

**What would the create action of viewed_lesson controller should look like?**

**There is only a create method needed. 
And how would the button/form would look like in the view? The button is placed in lectures/id/lesson/id**

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like following:

```
class ViewedLessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user_and_lesson
  def create
    @viewed_lesson = ViewLession.new(user_id: @user.id, lession_id: @lesson.id, completed: true)
    if @viewed_lesson.save
      # redirect_to appropriate location
    else
      # take the appropriate action
    end
  end
end
```

In your `ApplicationController` class, you can do:

```
def set_user_and_lesson
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  @lesson = Lesson.find_by_id(params[:lesson_id])
end
```

You also need to define the routes for it, and remember, you need to have models as well for `ViewedLesson` and `ViewedCourse`.

Comment: Thanks man! any idea how the link button in the view would be? many thanks

Comment: @AdrienNhm That depends on how do you define the route. Anyhow, you need to pass `@user.id` and `@lesson.id` in it. Something like: `link_to 'Next', viewed_lessons_path(@user.id, @lesson.id, completed: true)

Comment: @AdrienNhm If you think this is the valid answer, and helped you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your design sounds a little bit off. In rails there is not always a 1:1 crud relation between models and controllers.

First off I would rename those models `UserLesson` and `UserCouse`. It makes the relation really obvious and `ViewedLesson` stinks because it implies some sort of state.

In Rails a 1:1 relation between models and controllers is not always the best solution. And sometimes just using the standard crud verbs might not cut it.

Imagine the follow scenarios:

Does `POST /user/1/lessons` mean that a user has completed a course? 
Or does it mean the user has just started a lesson?

Instead you might want to do a design like the following:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :lessons # Used by admins to CRUD the curriculum.

resources :users
  resources :lessons, controller: `users/lessons` do
    member do 
      post :complete
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/users/lessons_controller.rb
module Users
  class LessonsController
    before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :update, :complete] 

    # ...
    # Enroll user in a lession
    # POST /users/:user_id/lessons/:id
    def create
      @user_lesson = UserLesson.create(lesson: params[:id], user: params[:user_id])
    end

    # POST /users/:user_id/lessons/:id/complete
    def complete
      # @todo check if user has completed all steps...
    end

    # Save user progress when they reach certain milestones
    def update
      # @todo update user_lesson
    end

    def set_lesson
      @lesson = Lession.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_user_lesson
      @user_lesson = UserLesson.find_by(user: params[:user_id], lession_id: params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

Another alternative would be if you don't want to nest the routes under `users`:

```
resources :lessions, controller: 'user_lessions' do
  member do 
    post :complete
  end
end

# or
resources :courses, controller: 'user_courses' do
  resources :lessions, controller: 'user_lessions' do
    member do 
      post :complete
    end
  end
end

namespace :admin do
  resources :lessions # used to crud the corriculum
end
```